# Android NDK - Can't use stl map emplace

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, android-ndk

Using android-ndk-r9c, eclipse.
I have this in Application.mk:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
```

And this in Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include

# Add your application source files here...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c \
    animation.cpp \
    camera.cpp \
    entities.cpp \
    graphics.cpp \
    input.cpp \
    level.cpp \
    physics.cpp \
    tiles.cpp \
    utils.cpp \
    main.cpp \

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a`

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried so many things, but the compiler keeps saying " ... has no member named 'emplace'"

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ Standard Library (`libstdc++`) is v4.6, which is too old to provide
`std::map::emplace`. You require GCC >= v4.8 and its library, or else replace the `emplace` calls with equivalent calls to `insert`

Comment: I am getting extreme amount of errors if I change 4.6 to 4.8 in Android.mk. Here it is - http://pastebin.com/iQJ5Crdt. It's strange why it tells me I don't use `-std=gnu++11` even though it's written in Application.mk

Comment: You can't just change "4.6" to "4.8" in the makefile! You would have to *use* GCC 4.8 as your compiler, with an appropriate makefile. Much simpler just to change the `emplace` calls to equivalent `insert` calls. Google `std::map::emplace`and `std::map::insert` to understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Actually, it looks like you have a typo. The second LOCAL_C_INCLUDES should be a += instead of :=

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
```

---

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
```